# return pydantic model with field names instead of alias as fastapi response

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I am trying to return my model with the defined field names instead of its aliases.

```py
class FooModel(BaseModel):
    foo: str = Field(..., alias="bar")

@app.get("/") -> FooModel:
    return FooModel(**{"bar": "baz"})
```

The response will be `{"bar": "baz"}` while I want `{"foo": "baz"}`. I know it's somewhat possible when using the `dict` method of the model, but it doesn't feel right and messes up the typing of the request handler.

```py
@app.get("/") -> FooModel:
    return FooModel(**{"bar": "baz"}).dict(by_alias=False)
```

I feel like it should be possible to set this in the [config class](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/), but I can't find the right option.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can add `response_model_by_alias=False` to path operation decorator. This key is mentioned [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/?h=response_model_by_alias#response_model_include-and-response_model_exclude) in the documentation.

For example:

```
@app.get("/model", response_model=Model, response_model_by_alias=False)
def read_model():
    return Model(alias="Foo")
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you know how to make the docs show the the same fields? At the moment they show the alias as response and as schema which isnt great.

Comment: I’m afraid this is impossible. According to [that](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/pull/1642) solution is to create another output model.

Comment: alright. Now thinking about and experimenting with it, Isn't your example flawed in that it will   serialize and validate the data twice? Should we not just return a dict from the handler, since fastapi will take the return value and stick it into the provided model class?

Comment: fastapi, will check what type is returned. So it wont serialize twice. https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/5905c3f740c8590f1a370e36b99b760f1ee7b828/fastapi/routing.py#L71