# Pydantic convert underscores in keys to hyphen when exporting to json

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a class

```py
class SampleModel(BaseModel):
    first_name: str
    last_name int
```

When I export it to json, I want to json to be

```json
{
    "first-name": "john doe",
    "last-name": 1234
}
```

I was going to use aliases, but does pydantic have a config or an option to directly do this for all fields in a model?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to change the output alias in pydantic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69306103/is-it-possible-to-change-the-output-alias-in-pydantic)

Comment: The approach I was looking for was to use Alias Generators.

Answer (score 0):

Pydantic has an [Alias Generator](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/#alias-generator) which can be used.